# run Excel Solver from macro

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I want to run Excels Solver from a Macro. I already have all the algorithm parameters manually entered into the Solver window. By just calling

```
SolverSolve
```

I get a compile error.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set a reference to the Solver addin in Tools/References:

1. Select References from the Tools menu in the Excel VBA editor window.
2. Check the "Solver" checkbox.
3. Click OK.

Comment: thank you, you are right. I was reading about that but for some reason Excel disabled the reference option initially, so I just had to restart it